# Why can't I send the logged in user data to vue using Auth::id()?

Tags: authentication, vue.js, laravel-5

Why it doesn't work with `Auth::id()`, but works with a hardcoded value like `1`.
The following doesn't work:

```
public function getTwitterUser()
{
    $auth_id = Auth::id();
    $getuser = Twitterac::where('user_id', $auth_id)->get();
    return $getuser;
}
```

But this does:

```
public function getTwitterUser()
{
    $auth_id = 1;
    $getuser = Twitterac::where('user_id', $auth_id)->get();
    return $getuser;
}
```

Comment: Well, is a user logged in? Print out the value of `Auth::id()` and `Auth::user()` with something like `dd` and see.

Comment: Probably Auth::id() is null?

Comment: yes user is logged in and the value of Auth::id() is not null.